# How to show a cell(column with its row values) of a pdftable(iTextSharp) in next line c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am generating a PDF document with a `PdfPTable`. There are three columns say *Col a*, *Col b*, and *Col c*. Currently it looks coming like this:

```
Col a         | Col b         | Col c
--------------------------------------------------------
ValuesofCol a | ValuesofCol b | ValuesofCol c
```

But as the *Col c* is the description, it contains a lot of data and I want the table to look like this:

```
Col a                      | Col b
--------------------------------------------------------
ValueofCol a               | ValueofColb
--------------------------------------------------------
Col c
--------------------------------------------------------
ValueOfCol c
--------------------------------------------------------
Cola                       | ColB
--------------------------------------------------------
ValueofCol a               | ValueofCol b
--------------------------------------------------------
Colc
--------------------------------------------------------
ValueOfCol c
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is code snippet i have written

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.SpacingBefore = 10f;
table.SpacingAfter = 10f;
table.TotalWidth = 550f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 2f, 3f, 3f };
table.SetWidths(widths);

//Header
table.AddCell(CreateHeaderCell("Cola"));
table.AddCell(CreateHeaderCell("Colb "));
table.AddCell(CreateHeaderCell("Colc"));

//Row 1
if (DsetAssesmentSummary.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    table.AddCell(CreateCell(DsetAssesmentSummary.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Cola"].ToString(), true));
 }
 if (DsetAssesmentSummary.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     table.AddCell(CreateCell(DsetAssesmentSummary.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Colb"].ToString(), true));
 }
 if (DsetAssesmentSummary.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
    table.AddCell(CreateCell(DsetAssesmentSummary.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Colc"].ToString(), true));
 }
```

Comment: look at what you have for the following `Col c` so perhaps it should be defined as `Colc`

Comment: Hi MethodMan- Thanks for ur response, i had given a dummy column name as Colc. Bruno's post helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [SimpleTable9](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable9) example.
It creates the PDF shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

If you want all the data in a single row, you could change the widths of the columns and make sure that the third column has more place than the first two rows.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.setSpacingBefore(5);
table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 8});
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.addCell("Col a");
table.addCell("Col b");
table.addCell("Col c");
table.addCell("Value a");
table.addCell("Value b");
table.addCell("This is a long description for column c. It needs much more space hence we made sure that the third column is wider.");
document.add(table);
```

If you want only two columns, then you need to create a table with only two columns.

```
table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setSpacingBefore(5);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.getDefaultCell().setColspan(1);
table.addCell("Col a");
table.addCell("Col b");
table.addCell("Value a");
table.addCell("Value b");
table.getDefaultCell().setColspan(2);
table.addCell("Value b");
table.addCell("This is a long description for column c. It needs much more space hence we made sure that the third column is wider.");
table.getDefaultCell().setColspan(1);
table.addCell("Col a");
table.addCell("Col b");
table.addCell("Value a");
table.addCell("Value b");
table.getDefaultCell().setColspan(2);
table.addCell("Value b");
table.addCell("This is a long description for column c. It needs much more space hence we made sure that the third column is wider.");
document.add(table);
```